# CSS: Should I avoid mixing height/width with border widths or is there a best practice for this?

Tags: css

In my online text editor I get the warning when I specify both height/width together with a border in a CSS-file (see the picture below). I understand the message and that it *could* have an unwanted impact on my design... But in this case it's no problem for me.

But it raises a more general question: Is there a smart way to work with both height/widths together with a border width? Some best practice?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) css property to handle it

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.

You can use `box-sizing: border-box` if you want the width and height include any border or padding you added. More details can be found in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).